# C programming Patterns to print the following pattern

Tags: c, char, printf, nested-loops, c-strings

i had try to print the following pattern but i only able to decrease the letters from the one side but not from both the side

Please someone help me with this :
to print this pattern

[image: Using C Programming]

this is the code that i use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char str[] = "Programming";
   int len = strlen(str);

   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      for (int j = i; j<len; j++) {
              printf("%c", str[j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to stop printing one letter earlier every iteration as well, so write j < len - i instead of j < len

Comment: In the second `for` loop go to `len - i`. (`for (int j = i; j<len - i; j++)`)

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, post text as text.

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pointer arithmetic, you can advance the start position of the printing, while specifying a length to `printf()` can be helpful, if you don't want to modify the string (in this case, we shorten the length by two, while advancing the pointer one position:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* for each command line parameter passed to the program */
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {

        /* use a copy of the argv[i] pointer */
        char *s = argv[i];

        /* ... and print */
        for (int l = strlen(s); l > 0; l -= 2) {
            printf("%.*s\n", l, s++);
        }
    }
}
```

In the case you want a minimum code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char *s = "Programming";
    for (int l = strlen(s); l > 0; l -= 2)
        printf("%.*s\n", l, s++);
}
```

or a pattern_print routine:

```
void print_pattern(const char *s)
{
    for (int l = strlen(s); l > 0; l -= 2)
        printf("%.*s\n", l, s++);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[KISS Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) solutions have the advantage of both running fast and being easy to read all at once:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
  char str[] = "Programming";
  int len = strlen(str);

  for (int i = 0; str[i]!='\0'; i++) 
  {
    puts(&str[i]);
    str[len-i-1] = '\0';
  }
}
```

Make a copy of `str` first in case the data needs to be preserved.

Comment: *Make a copy of `str` first in case the data needs to be preserved.*  I'll just note that if this code is used in a function, it doggone well better make a copy of the string first because someone is likely to pass in a string literal at some point...

Comment: @AndrewHenle In production quality code with functions, each parameter is documented. The documentation would mention modifying a parameter, as well as who is responsible of handling allocation caller/callee. So I don't see how that could be a problem.

Comment: Apparently, **your** customers use "reading and comprehension skills" in their hiring processes...

Answer (score 2):

There are several logical errors.

Firstly, the outer for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

specifies incorrect number of iterations. According to the loop the number of iteration is equal to `len`. However actually the number of iteration should be equal to `( len + 1 ) / 2`.

Secondly the inner for loop

```
  for (int j = i; j<len; j++) {
          printf("%c", str[j]);
  }
```

outputs characters up to the value of `len` while `len` should be decreased each time after the inner for loop.

You could write a separate function as for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_pattern( const char *s )
{
    for (const char *first = s, *last = s + strlen( s ); first < last; ++first, --last )
    {
        printf( "%.*s\n", ( int )( last - first ), first );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "Programming";

    print_pattern( s );
}
```

The program output is

```
Programming
rogrammin
ogrammi
gramm
ram
a
```

The function will work if the length of the passed string can fit in object of the type `int`. Otherwise you can use nested for loops similarly your nested for loops like

```
void print_pattern( const char *s )
{
    for (const char *first = s, *last = s + strlen( s ); first < last; ++first, --last )
    {
        for (const char *current = first; current != last; ++current)
        {
            putchar( *current );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

Shortly speaking your for loops should look something like the following way

```
for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen( str ); i < n; i++, n-- )
{
    for ( size_t j = i; j < n; j++ )
    {
        putchar( str[j] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Anybody said you must preserve the string untouched during printing?

You can truncate the string by overwriting the last character with zero in every iteration. At the same time you can advance the starting point for printing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char str[] = "Programming";

    char *head = str;
    char *tail = str + strlen(str);

    while (head < tail) 
    {
        puts(head++);
        *--tail = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This yields nearly identical machine code as my answer. So I guess it's just a matter of taste which you find most readable. Personally I avoid mixing ++/-- with other operators or function calls in the same expression.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is similar to Vlad's, but uses `%*.*s` instead of just `%.*s`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char txt[] = "Programming";
    int len = strlen(txt);
    
    for(int i=0; i<=len/2; ++i)
    {
        printf("%*.*s\n", len-2*i, len-2*i, txt+i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```